# multiple vennDiagrams in one plot R

Tags: r, plot, venn-diagram

I would like to make many venn diagrams in one plot in R. 
I tried using the venneuler packages (and using par(mfrow=c(2,1))), however i would like that a circle in one venn diagram has the same size in all diagrams - if the value is the same.

When I do

`require(venneuler)
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(venneuler(c(A=1, B=8, "A&B"=1)))
plot(venneuler(c(A=1, C=1, "A&C"=1)))`

I get
[image]

But A in the first plot, should be same size as A and C in the second

Comment: But what size should B be in the first plot then?

Comment: @TylerRinker: But that will still give the same result. The problem is that the biggest value in each vennDiagram is set to fill the entire plot. John: B should have an area 8 times as big as A and C

Comment: I tried a few techniques, but I think you may have to resort to recoding `venneuler:::plot.VennDiagram` by hand. Luckily, it's relatively short, and incorporating some cognizance of `xlim` and `ylim` shouldn't be too hard ...

Comment: ... perhaps the problem is in `venneuler()` itself, which appears to be doing the auto-scaling for you. That function is s bit more work to modify. Perhaps you could contact the [maintainer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/venneuler/index.html)? It hasn't been touched in almost four years, though ...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly my problem. Do anyone know if there is a venndiagram package, where you can choose you own scaling?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with my r package **eulerr**. It returns grid graphics objects that can be arranged using the excellent **gridExtra** package.

```
library(eulerr)

p1 <- plot(euler(c(A = 1, B = 8, "A&B" = 1)))
p2 <- plot(euler(c(A = 1, C = 1, "A&C" = 1)))

gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

[image]

Comment: This code doesn't generate the plot that you linked to, how does one generate the plot?